# Set a mock GPS location on an Android device

Tags: c#, android, nunit

I am working on automating some device/server testing we do on various android devices.  I need a way to set a specific GPS lat/long on an actual Android device that is usable within a NUnit testing framework.  Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set **Allow mock locations true under Developer settings**. After that you can write some small utility app which will set mock location on receiving some custom event.

You can then set location using adb shell command
e.g

```
$ adb shell
am start -a android.intent.action.SET_CUSTOM_MOCK_LOCATION -d gps://lat-long
```

You can receive this information in your utility app and set mock location. Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for bringing up this old question. But I'm supposed to add 'SET_CUSTOM_MOCK_LOCATION' to the android.intent.action package. Or is my understanding wrong here?

I just asked a pretty semilar question in the Android SE maybe you can give me an answer. Id really really appreciate that. 

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/121120/setting-mock-location-remotely