# Is there an ADB command to toggle Allow Mock Locations?

Tags: android, adb

I've searched through some topics but haven't found an answer. I need not to specify lat/long but turn the switch of allowing mock locations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a mock GPS location on an Android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976506/set-a-mock-gps-location-on-an-android-device)

Comment: Check also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753097/how-to-set-allow-mock-location-on-android-device-before-executing-androidtest-wi/39765423#39765423

Answer (score 9):

In Marshmallow (and above) after you have installed your app, just run:

```
adb shell appops set com.example.my.package android:mock_location allow
```

hope this helps!

Some internals: the string android:mock_location is resolved by the AppOpsManager into an actual int and than executed.

Comment: Is there any way to execute this via android test? Like in a setup method annotated with before(). I don't want to use adb for that. Any suggestion? I need to run it automatically before executing the test itself.

Comment: And how do you turn mock locations off via adb?

Comment: Anybody found way to change allow mock location settings in pre-marshmallow?

Comment: @Raj same command but change allow to deny

Comment: @chikka.anddev I think you are looking for this command: `adb shell settings put secure mock_location 1` Use 1 to enable and 0 to disable.

Comment: @penguin359 does this work on android 11?