# How to initialize emulated external dependencies in a Kotlin Android UI test

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, mockito, dagger-2

I'll be developing an Android app in Kotlin and I'm trying to figure out how to initialize emulated dependencies.  For example, the app will make API calls to a server, obtain the user's location from a location provider, pull down images from a content management system, store data locally in a database and in Android's Shared Preferences, and do math based on the current date/time.  Thus there are a lot of external dependencies I want to emulate, including the current date/time so I can verify age calculation, etc.

My goal for testing is just to validate my app's screens using an Android instrumented test.  I don't want any dependency on real external systems because testing those systems is the responsibility of the developers of those systems.

While reading Android'd documentation [Consider whether to use test doubles](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals#test-doubles), I noticed it offered a good tip: "Tip: Check with the library authors to see if they provide any officially-supported testing infrastructures, such as fakes, that you can reliably depend on."  However, the documentation doesn't really explain how to initialize a 3rd party test infrastructure.

Below are what I understand so far about my options, but they all come back to a fundamental thing I don't understand: how does an Android app under test know it should operate in a test mode vs. a production mode?

1. **Mocking such as Mockito or MockK:**  Mocking seems like a special case of Dependency Injection tailored for testing.  The examples I've seen involve testing a class or a method, not a full scale system.  The examples typically show how you mock a class and pass it to the class/method under test.  But with a full scale system, the test code operates on widgets referenced via Espresso.  There is no access to the classes where the logic is.  My impression is mocking is for unit testing, not UI testing.  But maybe someone can explain how to use mocking for UI testing:

   - a) Suppose an external dependency is initialized deep in the call stack.  If I define a mock in my test code's setup function (e.g. a method annotated with @Before), how do I pass that down to the place in the code that depends on it?
   - b) I keep reading that mocks don't work in Kotlin because Kotlin defines all classes as final.  There seem to be a few work arounds.  But does does Google/Android officially recommend one of these (I haven't read it in their documentation).
2. **Dependency Injection such as Dagger 2:**  If mocking isn't viable for UI testing, then should I use Dependency Injection?  From what I understand, it seems Dagger 2 deals with issue 1.a above by defining a top-level Component and a tree of Modules which can provide dependencies at any layer of the stack.  For testing, it seems like I would just provide a different Component that emulates the real dependencies.

   - a) In an Android instrumented test, where do instantiate a Dagger 2 Component designed for testing.  How do I make sure that Component is used rather than the Component intended for production?
3. **Prepare before launching test:**  I can see how I could customize build.gradle to prepare my test environment before my application is launched.  For example, I could pass a flag to my app so that when the Application's onCreate() gets called, I can configure my system to prepare emulated dependencies via Dependency Injection, Mocking, or even just a custom implementation.  For example, some external dependencies have a test mode where I would need to pass a flag to them so they work in test mode.  I'm not clear how that sort of thing reconciles with Dependency Injection or Mock but I guess I could see how I could use those mechanisms as a wrapper to pass the test flag or not.  In the following post someone wanted to mock a location provider and to do that they modified their build.gradle file to set things up before the Android test infrastructure started.
   [How to set Allow Mock Location on Android Device before executing AndroidTest with uiautomator and espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753097/how-to-set-allow-mock-location-on-android-device-before-executing-androidtest-wi/39765423#39765423)

In conclusion, I want to test a Kotlin Android app's UI using Android instrumented test with Espresso but I don't know how to setup the test so that external dependencies use emulation code rather than production code.  Should I use mocking, Dependency Injection, or customize via build.gradle?  Can someone help me get my thinking on track?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I've discovered that the Android [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule) allows you to defer launching the Activity.  This gives the test code time to initialize emulated dependencies as demonstrated in [Fast Mocked UI Tests on Android Kotlin](https://medium.com/@elye.project/fast-mocked-ui-tests-on-android-kotlin-89ed0a8a351a).