# Espresso tests with mock location on Google Firebase Test Lab

Tags: firebase, mocking, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I developed Android Espresso tests and I want to test some location changes in my app. I have tests that fail because they must run on a device located in national territory (Portugal).I mocked the location and I needed also to enable the application in the devs options using an ADB command: [How to write Espresso Tests which are mocking GPS locations and use them in Google Testlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440243/how-to-write-espresso-tests-which-are-mocking-gps-locations-and-use-them-in-goog) and [How to set Allow Mock Location on Android Device before executing AndroidTest with uiautomator and espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753097/how-to-set-allow-mock-location-on-android-device-before-executing-androidtest-wi)
However, it's not working yet. On Firebase Test Lab is displayed the following message: “Your access is being made outside Portugal".
What can i do to fix this?

Thanks,
xptoGirl

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440243/how-to-write-espresso-tests-which-are-mocking-
Gps-locations-and-use-them-in-goog